# Arduino: library not found

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to build a sketch that I downloaded from github:

https://github.com/Murphy3220/Razor-AHRS-SEN-14001

...and get the following error:

```
Archiving built core (caching) in: /tmp/arduino_cache_578662/core/core_SparkFun_samd_samd21_9dof_73bc95c36c92dd5071665d4df9b2bc75.a
Sketch uses 48472 bytes (18%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
/home/cbrown/.arduino15/packages/SparkFun/tools/bossac/1.4.0/bossac: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/cbrown/.arduino15/packages/SparkFun/tools/bossac/1.4.0/bossac)
/home/cbrown/.arduino15/packages/SparkFun/tools/bossac/1.4.0/bossac: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/cbrown/.arduino15/packages/SparkFun/tools/bossac/1.4.0/bossac)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What board are you trying to upload to?  I've seen this happen when uploading code to a variant board that it wasn't designed for.

Comment: Thanks for the question. The board is the Sparkfun sen-14001, which is what the code is written/modified to work with. I should also note that I get the same error when trying to build the firmware provided by sparkfun: https://github.com/sparkfun/9DOF_Razor_IMU/